# GlobalContext is not update in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to create GlobalContext but when I update this inside Class Component it didn't work in Class Component  it's showing value of `globalState` but it's not updating `globalState` via `setGlobalState`

**GlobalContext**

```js
import React, { useState ,ReactNode} from 'react'

const initialMapContext: { globalState: any; setGlobalState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>> } = {
  globalState: {}, 
  // will update to the reducer we provide in MapProvider
  setGlobalState: () => {},
};
const GlobalContext = React.createContext(initialMapContext );
interface Props {  children?: ReactNode;}

export function GlobalProvider({children}:Props){
  const [ globalState, setGlobalState ] = useState({name:'pranjal'}); 
  return <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ globalState, setGlobalState }}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>;
}
export default GlobalContext
```

my code in classComponent is

```js
static contextType = GlobalContext; 
getData = async () =>{
const { globalState, setGlobalState } = this.context;
console.log(globalState);    // pranjal
setGlobalState({name:"please login"});
console.log(globalState);   // pranjal


// my rest code 
}
```

but `setGlobalState` is not updating `globalState` value .

Although it works fine in the Functional component

**Function.js**

```js
  const { globalState, setGlobalState } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  setGlobalState({name:'Please login'})
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in a class component. This is well covered in several places in the official documentation, including e.g. [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both).

Comment: @JaredSmith may be you are right but I have a doubt that why it is working inside render ?

Comment: What do you mean "it is working inside render"?

Comment: @JaredSmith I mean when I am trying to update globalState outside render function  it didn't work. but inside `render(){}` it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `static contextType = GlobalContext;` , I would recommend you to use a Higher Order Component (HOC) which wraps a component with your GlobalContext.

Impementation:

**GlobalContext**

Export one HOC method called withGlobalContext as follows,

```
export const withGlobalContext = (Component) => (props) => (
  <GlobalContext.Consumer>
   {({ globalState, setGlobalState }) => (
        <Component
          globalState={globalState}
          setGlobalState={setGlobalState}
          {...props}
        />
   )}
</GlobalContext.Consumer>
)
```

**ClassComponent**

Wrap the component with the HOC, to get the global context values as the props. And being available in the props, you can use it anywhere in the component, even outside `render()`

```
class ClassComponent extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.globalState)
  console.log(this.props.setGlobalState)
}

render() {
    return (
     // Your JSX here
    )
  }

export default withGlobalContext(ClassComponent)
```

Also, I prefer exporting a custom hook, for using context in functional components, rather than using `useContext`

Implementation:

```
export function useGlobalContext() {
  const context = useContext(GlobalContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('You did something wrong')
  }
  return [context.globalState, context.setGlobalState]
}
```

Then in your functional component, use it like following:

```
function FunctionalComponent(){
  const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useGobalContext()
  return (
    // Your JSX here
  )
}
```

Cheers!